# Conditional extraction from a large list

Tags: r

I am trying to make a wordcloud of all the messages I have sent on Facebook. I have downloaded all the messages in the format json from Facebook and imported them into **R**. They are now organised as a large list with the following pattern

```
Content
-> [no of conversation (goes down to 1445)
  -> messages 
    -> sender_name
    -> content
```

Where the sender_name is the person who sent the message and content is the actual message. My aim in the end is to make a list of all the messages that I have sent. I have been able to make it for one conversation using the following code:

```
Person1_messages<-content$`messages_all/inbox/conversation1/message.json`$messages$content
Person1_sender_name<-content$`messages_all/inbox/conversation1/message.json`$messages$sender_name
Person1<-cbind(Person1_messages,Person1_sender_name)

Person1.dta<-data.frame(Person1)
newdata <- Person1[ which(Person1.dta$Person1_sender_name=='My name')]
```

Ideally I would like to do this for all my conversations. My question is thus how I could loop this to get my messages from all conversations?

This would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to make this question more specific, providing sample data, reproducible example and desired output. Please consider referring to [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) and making your post reproducible.

Comment: I would use the apply function to build a filtered list, like: apply(1:length(content), function(messages_index) filter_function_you_need_to_build(messages_index));